# Giving index numbers to time

Tags: r, indexing, time

I have a column of time

```
a = times('00:00:00', '00:15:00', '01:45:00', '23:45:00')
```

And I would like to give them an index based on a 15 min interval. So for example, 00:00:00 will be 1, 00:15:00 will be 2, and 23:45:00 will be 96 as there are ninety-six 15 min intervals in a 24hr period.

So the result I want is:

```
1 2 8 96
```

Comment: what is `times`?

Comment: Could be from *lubridate* package?

Comment: @zx8754 That was my first guess as well, but nop

Answer (score 2):

Another fun idea,

```
cumsum(c(1, diff(strptime(a, format = "%T")) / 15))
#[1]  1  2  8 96
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `cut` with `breaks` of `"15 mins"` after converting `a` to time object and convert the levels to numeric.

```
as.integer(cut(strptime(a, format = "%T"), breaks = "15 mins"))
#[1]  1  2  8 96
```

Same would also work with `as.POSIXct`

```
as.integer(cut(as.POSIXct(a, format = "%T"), breaks = "15 mins"))
```

---

Using `lubridate` we can convert to seconds and do

```
library(lubridate)
period_to_seconds(hms(a))/(15*60) + 1
```

Or with `minute`

```
minute(as.period(hms(a), "minutes"))/15 + 1
```

You might need `ceiling`/`floor` based on the time duration to round values.

**data**

```
a <- c('00:00:00', '00:15:00', '01:45:00', '23:45:00')
```